# Any way to fix this out of memory error installing @salesforce/sfdx-scanner?

Tags: salesforcedx, sfdx-plugin, continuous-integration, github-actions

We run our CI (Continuous Integration) build for our app using [GitHub actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions) and part of that is to install and run the [Salesforce CLI Scanner](https://forcedotcom.github.io/sfdx-scanner/). We run on `ubuntu-latest` that is documented to have "7 GB of RAM memory".

But starting late yesterday, the install `sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/sfdx-scanner` is failing with this JavaScript out of memory error:

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xb00d90 node::Abort() [/home/runner/sfdx/bin/node]
 2: 0xa1823b node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [/home/runner/sfdx/bin/node]
 3: 0xcedbce v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/home/runner/sfdx/bin/node]
 4: 0xcedf47 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/home/runner/sfdx/bin/node]
 5: 0xea6105  [/home/runner/sfdx/bin/node]
 6: 0xea6be6  [/home/runner/sfdx/bin/node]
 7: 0xeb4b1e  [/home/runner/sfdx/bin/node]
 8: 0xeb5560 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/home/runner/sfdx/bin/node]
 9: 0xeb8455 v8::internal::Heap::HandleGCRequest() [/home/runner/sfdx/bin/node]
10: 0xe459c7 v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts() [/home/runner/sfdx/bin/node]
11: 0x11f2655 v8::internal::Runtime_StackGuard(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/home/runner/sfdx/bin/node]
12: 0x15e7819  [/home/runner/sfdx/bin/node]
    Error: yarn add @salesforce/sfdx-scanner@latest --non-interactive 
    --mutex=file:/home/runner/.local/share/sfdx/yarn.lock 
    --preferred-cache-folder=/home/runner/.cache/sfdx/yarn --check-files 
    exited with code null
```

Any insight or advice on how to fix appreciated.

**PS**

Adding this `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096` to give Node more memory didn't help.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the space size further or updating node (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59572966/1023542)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: This has been fixed. You should see no error installing plugins now

---

This is a [noted issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1319) that isn't specific to `sfdx-scanner`, but installing plugins. Based on info in that issue, it seems the root cause is this [current bug](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/8734) in yarn that oclif uses to install plugins. There's a created issue for [oclif](https://github.com/oclif/oclif/issues/758) as well.

There's a [fix](https://github.com/oclif/command/pull/301) in the works, but doesn't seem to mention a timeline.

On my end, your command actually worked fine but I see the error with all other plugins I attempted.

It does seem a current workaround can be [building it locally](https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-scanner/blob/dev/CONTRIBUTING.md#building-locally) until the above is fixed.

1. Clone sfdx-scanner through git

`git clone https://github.com/forcedotcom/sfdx-scanner.git`

2. Build it using yarn

```
cd sfdx-scanner
yarn --ignore-scripts && yarn build
```

3. Then, link the module to sfdx

`sfdx plugins: link .`

Comment: Thanks Kris - helpful to know what to keep an eye on and to have the work-around.

Comment: Thanks for the "this had been fixed update".